# Google not working for me

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

I seem to have some sort of problem with Google.

My Gmail account in Mail is marked with a little 'problem squiggle'. Connection Doctor says that login to both the IMAP and SMTP server failed.
If I click on the squiggle, I get a dialog saying "enter the password for the account in Safari".
This brings up a window in Safari that stays blank.

Google searches in Safari also do nothing, just sitting there, until eventually saying "Failed to Open Page".

Google Books, Maps, Translate, and all other Google services just don't work.

All other websites and email accounts work fine. I have tried different DNS servers. Google services work fine using another browser (Vivaldi).

This on Mojave. I suspect it's something to do with 'certificates' or some such.

The problem is intermittent, but occurs often. Despite this, I have actually had some email through on my Gmail account, while it claims to be not working.

Comment: I assume you rebooted already? Did you try with a different account on your Mac?

Comment: Yes, it happens intermittently across several reboots; over weeks. I doubt the user account is an issue because other browsers are unaffected. I could try trashing Safari user prefs and caches though.